# Pulling from remote master branch after sending a pull request

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request

Consider a `master` branch, whose commits are

```
A -> B -> C
```

I create a branch from this called the `test` branch
Now my current state of the branch is

```
A -> B -> C
```

I made some changes, and now the state is

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

I made a pull request now (with 1 file changed), where I had some corrections to do.

I directly made changes to the `test` branch and pushed it. Now it looks like this.

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

The pull request reflected the changes automatically. (2 files changed)

Now when I observed, the state of main branch is

```
A -> B -> C -> X -> Y
```

Now, I pulled these new changes from the `master` branch to my `test` branch. If I push these changes to the remote `test` branch, will it get reflected in the Pull request I made?

I want the pull request to be purely the two files that I made? Will pushing these changes from the `master` branch show up on the Pull Request page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pull Request will likely show three commits: `D`, `E` and `M`. `M` will be a merge commit that brings changes from `X` and `Y` into your `test` branch.

Most Pull Request interfaces will show you the `M` commit, but the diff will not show the changes that are already in `main`/`master`.